# Are volume of solids & liquid totally independent of pressure

Tags: material-science

In my book it is written as

$GASEOUS$ $STATE$ : The state is characterized by sensitivity of volume change with change of pressure and temperature.

Now my doubt is that are volume of $solids$ & $liquid$ totally independent of pressure??

I searched on internet but do not get any proper answer .

Comment: http://water.usgs.gov/edu/compressibility.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the volume of liquids and solids *does* depend on pressure. However, the volume of gases is drastically *more sensitive* to pressure. (This property is known as [compressibility](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility?wprov=sfla1).)

In most contexts, the dependence of volume on pressure for liquids and especially solids is considered negligible (that is, most liquids and solids are approximately incompressible). In mathematical terms, this means $\frac{dV}{dP} \approx 0$ (the rate of change of volume with respect to pressure is essentially zero).

As before stated, the volume of *gases* depends significantly on pressure. In fact, in the [ideal gas model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas?wprov=sfla1) (a good approximation for most gases), the two "state variables" are inversely proportional: $V \propto \frac{1}{P}$ ([Boyle's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle%27s_law?wprov=sfla1)).